# Zend Mail SMTP Gmail issue

Tags: magento2, smtp

I am receiving the following error:

```
[2021-02-25 12:37:07] main.CRITICAL: Could not read from smtp.gmail.com {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): Could not read from smtp.gmail.com at /var/www/html/hoesjes/app/code/Mageplaza/Smtp/Mail/Transport.php:134, Zend\\Mail\\Protocol\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Could not read from smtp.gmail.com at /var/www/html/hoesjes/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php:305)"} []
[2021-02-25 12:37:07] main.CRITICAL: Warning: fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1420C0CF:SSL routines:ssl_write_internal:protocol is shutdown in /var/www/html/hoesjes/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php on line 260 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): Warning: fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
```

The interesting part is that this message is showing up after I've sent exactly 96 emails out :) so when i am doing a mass email send out.

Is there a limit or something which prevents `smtp.gmail.com` to send out more then 96 emails in one go ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a limit :(, according to https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en daily smtp mail limit is 100

> Recipients per message sent via SMTP (by POP or IMAP users) or the Gmail API
> Addresses in the To, Cc, and Bcc fields of a single email. Includes email sent using smtp-relay.gmail.com or smtp.gmail.com* **==> 100**

Comment: Hi @Mehmed is there a way to increase that limit ?

Comment: I believe no, you should look something like mailchimp, mailgun for sending mail purpose. You can keep to use gmail while you're using mailchimp or mailgun.

Comment: Ok, thnx a lot for your answer